# problema al ejecutar instrucciones SQL

Tags: java, sql, java-swing

estoy terminando un proyecto, el cual en una ventana diseñada con Java, y dentro de esta ventana con dos textArea y un botón. Se escriben unas instrucciones SQL en el textArea, se selecciona la que se quiere ejecutar y al darle al botón dependiendo de lo que contenga ese String, pues ejecuta un método u otro.

Adjutno fragmento de código del ActionPerformed:

```
jbRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String seleccion = jtaConsulta.getSelectedText();
            if(jtaConsulta.getText().contains("select")){
                jtaResultado.setText(bd.consulta(jtaConsulta.getSelectedText())); 
            }
            else if(jtaConsulta.getText().contains("insert") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("update") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("delete")){
                    jtaResultado.setText(String.valueOf(bd.consultaAccion(seleccion)));
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error global");
            }
        }
    });
```

lo que hace es preguntar, si la cadena contiene "select" llama al método consulta y hace un select de la tabla y ya está. Si contiene "update" o "insert" o "delete" pues ejecuta el método consultaAcción que hace la operación correspondiente. Pero aquí es donde tengo el problema, yo escribo mis sentencias SQL y selecciono la que quiero ejecutar (para eso tengo el método getSelectedText()) y para el select ningún problema, pero si quiero hacer update, me devuelve el catch de mi excepción, diciendo pues el mensaje que le he puesto ahí en caso de que ocurra algún error.

Si en vez de usar else if(condicion), pongo if, como en este fragmento de código:

```
jbRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String seleccion = jtaConsulta.getSelectedText();
            if(jtaConsulta.getText().contains("select")){
                jtaResultado.setText(bd.consulta(jtaConsulta.getSelectedText())); 
            }
            if(jtaConsulta.getText().contains("insert") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("update") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("delete")){
                    jtaResultado.setText(String.valueOf(bd.consultaAccion(seleccion)));
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error global");
            }
        }
    });
```

las instrucciones se ejecutan perfectamente, pero todas y cada una de las instrucciones me devuelven los catch. No se como plantear el condicional, o si podría plantearlo de otra manera.

```
public String consulta(String consulta){
    String cadena = "";
    try {
        stmt = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);

        while(resultSet.next()){
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            int age = resultSet.getInt("age");
            String first = resultSet.getString("first");
            String last = resultSet.getString("last");

            cadena += "id: " + id + "\t" + age + "\t" + first + "\t" + last + "\n";
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al hacer la consulta select");
    }
return cadena;
}

public String consultaAccion(String consulta){
    int afectadas = 0;
    try {
        stmt = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        afectadas = stmt.executeUpdate(consulta);
        stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al hacer inserccion o actualización");
    }
return "Filas afectadas: " + afectadas;
}
```

gracias y un saludo

Comment: Si no pones el código donde se produce el error y la traza del error, es un poco difícil ayudarte.

Comment: lo he puesto, me da el error en el condicional este: else if(jtaConsulta.getText().contains("insert") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("update") || jtaConsulta.getText().contains("delete")){
                    jtaResultado.setText(String.valueOf(bd.consultaAccion(seleccion)));
            }

Comment: Hola. Quién sabe lo que pasa en los métodos `bd.consulta` y `bd.consultaAccion`... todo apunta a que el problema está ahí, no en las condicionales. Por tanto, deberías compartir el código de ambos métodos.

Comment: lo siento, ya los he añadido @A.Cedano

Comment: Pero que error se produce?

Comment: A simple vista no hay nada extraño. ¿Por qué no pones en los `catch` que te imprima el error exacto?  Puede haber algún error de sintaxis en la consulta o algo así. O sea, pon algo así:  **`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al hacer inserccion o actualización"+ex.getMessage());`** Lo mismo para el `catch` del `select`

Comment: ya lo he solucionado, estaba poniendo mal el condicional, en vez de jtaConsulta.getText().contains("insert") había que poner jtaConsulta.getSelectedText().contains("insert")

Comment: Ok. También puedes usar la variable `seleccion` para hacer las comparaciones. Así le das más legilibilidad al código: `if(seleccion.contains("select")){ //... }
            else if(seleccion.contains("insert") || seleccion.contains("update") || seleccion.contains("delete")){...`

Answer (score 0):

El usuario de la pregunta ya ha resuelto el problema.

> Estaba poniendo mal el condicional, en vez de
>   `jtaConsulta.getText().contains("insert") había que poner
>   jtaConsulta.getSelectedText().contains("insert")`.

@A. Cedano ha agregado la siguiente información:

> Para darle más legibilidad, también puede usar la variable `seleccion`
>   para hacer las comparaciones, así le da más legibilidad al código:
>   `if(seleccion.contains("select")){ //... } else
>   if(seleccion.contains("insert") || seleccion.contains("update") ||
>   seleccion.contains("delete")){...`

```
Ambos textos se encuentran en los comentarios de la respuesta.
```